# htaccess optimization

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=156&app=([a-z]+)
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ http://www.xyz.com/is2011/?app=%1  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=156
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ http://www.xyz.com/is2011/?  [R=301,L]
```

I just want to optimize the htaccess code. I want to merge the above two rules. Can i do the same? Please give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=156(&(app=([a-z]+)))?
RewriteRule ^events/(index.php)$ http://www.xyz.com/is2011/?%2  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanx roirodriguez. Its working :)(sorry for the late responding)

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^event_id=156(?:&(app=[a-z]+))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^events/index\.php$ http://www.xyz.com/is2011/?%1 [R=301,L,NC,NE,QSA]
```

Comment: thanx anubhava. But it give me internal server error every time. Even i modified your code. But it still give me 500 internal server error. But roirodriguez answer is working for me.